# Does the power series converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is (pi/4)^k.  I already know the series converges because it is a power series with r being less than one.  The problem is, I am not sure how to test it.  My first idea was to use the integral test but I am not sure.  I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "test it?" The series is actually not a power series, but a geometric series, but this justification works either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sum the geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^k=\frac{1}{1-\pi/4}$ since $\pi/4<1$.